# Using find on Linux to find files with group/other permissions that match

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I've got a need to find all files in a directory where the group and other permissions match (eg. those where the group membership of the file doesn't actually affect access).

Since there are only 8 possibilities for that (x00, x11, x22, etc.) I thought I could just search on those permissions but I can't find a way to explicitly match some of the permission bits without matching all of them (eg. match all of 000, 100, 200, 300, etc. for x00).

I've built a long find statement like:

`find . \(  \
 -perm 000 -o -perm 011 -o -perm 022 -o -perm 033 [...] \
 -perm 100 -o -perm 111 -o -perm 122 -o -perm 133 [...] \
[...]
\) -ls`

And it works but it seems very inelegant (it's over 8 characters...and that's before I've put any path selection clauses which will be needed...).

Is there a better way?

Edit: it just occurred to me that this ignores SUID/SGID permissions.  Adding those will make the command even longer...hopefully there's a better way!

Comment: Don't know the answer, but if I were trying to do this, I would start with a find that only excludes things you never want to see and then pipe the output into other filters like grep, sed, or awk where it's much easier (especially with awk) to solve the problem one piece at a time and add things like print statements to make sure that each part is doing what you want it to. Clarification? Permissions match what? What is the "macro" problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem with piping the output to other commands is mostly around "special" characters (especially spaces).  The "macro" problem is we'd like to change the group ID (the numeric one underneath the symbolic one) on a bunch of files (long story) but this is slow.  We realized we can change it on a bunch of the files where it doesn't really matter while the apps are up and focus our outage time on the smaller number where the group permissions actually matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm still not sure I understand the problem (probably not your fault!), but here are some ideas:

1) Use the `-print0` option of `find` (and similar options in `grep`, `xargs`, etc.) to deal with special characters in file names.

2) It might take some scripting foo to put it all together, but the [stat](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/82327-what-command-get-file-permission.html) command will return the octal permission string for a file. Then, all you have to do is break it up into three separate characters (e.g. 775 -> 7 7 5) (using bash parameter modifiers or string processing in the language/tool of your choice) and if the second or third character matches the first one, then you have identical permissions for the owner and group or other.

The improvement here is that you're looking at all three permissions at once instead of having to enumerate all the permutations. They're either the same triplet or they're not. It will take a bit more fiddling to handle permission strings more than 3 characters long (for things like sticky bits, etc.), but it's still basically an equal or not equal test to find the files in question.

I don't have time to figure out the details, but I'd start by seeing if I could craft a script that would:

1) Get and break up the permissions using `stat` and then check if there are permission matches. If there are, print the file name (possibly the full path) and the permissions or flags for what needs changing. If not, just discard that file name.

2) Either pipe the output of `find` into this script or access it with the `find` `-exec` option.

3) Then, you'd have a list of just the files which need to be modified along with what each one needs
   and that can be handled with simple scripting.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I've come to the same conclusion as Joe -- that what I want is too much to ask "find" to do alone.  The pointer that the other file manipulation commands support null terminated outputs for file names was very helpful as well.  Thanks all who took a moment to look.